# Java: Connect to a NAS with NFS technology

Tags: java, android, nfs, nas

I am programming software to send files from my Android device to a NAS of a friend of me over the network. I want to use Network File System to achieve this but I don't have any clue how to begin with this. I als can't find information on the internet to connect programmatically to a NAS drive over the network.

Can someone help me/give me an example/link/tutorial?

Any help is very welcome.

Comment: Where have you looked so far? What makes you believe that this is the right solution? Is NFS even compatible with Android?

Comment: I googled it, but didn't find anything, Android is Java, so what should be the other options?